# Using container_of with a pre-initialized struct

Tags: c, linux, struct, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Sorry that the title is a bit vague. Here is what I want to do.

First lets say there is the following struct.

```
struct info {
  struct device *dev
  int a;
  int b;
}
```

I allocate memory for this struct and assign values as the following.

```
struct info *i0;
i0 = kzalloc(sizeof(*i), GFP_KERNEL);
i0->dev = dev0; //dev is pre-initialized
i0->a = 0;
i0->b = 1;
```

I am unsure if I can use `container_of` with pre-initialized `dev0` that I used to assign to `i0->dev`. Something like below.

```
struct info * i1 = container_of(dev0, struct info, dev);
do_something(i1->a, i1->b);
```

Doing so gives the following error in the line of `container_of`.

```
error: undefined symbol: __compiletime_assert_###
```

Can someone help me understand the error and guide me on correct use of `container_of`? What would be a good workaround?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What does it mean "predefined" `dev0` ? How is it "predefined"?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry for confusion. I meant pre-initialized. So, not doing something like `device_initialize(i0->dev)`, but just assigning `i0->dev = dev0` where `dev0` is already initialized and used in somewhere.

Comment: No. dev0 has no way of knowing there is a pointer in a different struct.  That's not how container of works.

Comment: You can do `container_of(dev0, struct info, dev);` only if `dev0 == &(i0->dev)`.